# AWS DMS issue with source endpoint in EC2-classic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, mariadb, amazon-aurora

We are using several EC2-Classic servers (Linux Ubuntu) with following configuration: mounted EBS volumes and on them is running Server version: 5.5.48-MariaDB

I would like to use AWS DMS (AWS Database Migration Service) and to migrate our EBS DBs to the RDS AuroraDB in new VPC.
I created VPC, AuroraDB (not public accessible), AWS DMS replication instance and endpoints.

From EC2-classic instance I am able to open remote AuroraDB console (thanks to Classic Link), which is in the VPC.
Target endpoint (to the AuroraDB) works OK and TEST was finished successful

Source Endpoint show me following error:

```
Operation:testEndpointDetails:[errType=ERROR_RESPONSE,
status=122502, errMessage=Cannot connect to ODBC provider 122502 ODBC general error.,
errDetails= RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 2003 Message: unixODBCMySQL http://ODBC 5.3(w)
DriverCan't connect to MySQL server on 'Private.DNS.name' (110) http://122502] ODBC general error.
```

I tried to set like Server name
Private/Public DNS, and Private/Public IP, still same.

Credentials are OK, and I am not using any special characters. 
I am operate in North Virginia Region. 
AWS DMS replication instance is set as Public. 
I am able to log into MariaDB console from remote EC2-classic instance.

I tried set port 3306 and Private/Public IP of AWS DMS replication instance into right Security Groups, but I guess that I still miss something, probably in the SG area, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue with the same error message and it was a network issue. My replication instance didn't have access to the database.

My database is in a VPC with a subnet x and my replication instance is in the same VPC with the same subnet x. I opened the 3306 port in my Network ACL and in the security group of the database to the Internet (0.0.0.0/0) just to test if it was a network problem. The connection test worked with those settings. After the test, I removed the last setting for security.

The solution to my problem was to open the 3306 port in the security group and in the network ACL of the database to all the vpc connection. e.g. 172.0.0.0/16.

Hope it helps

Comment: Olivier, thank you for response. 
In the Network ACL I have allowed ALL Traffic (inbound / outbound) when I started to troubleshoot it..  
* I have allowed incoming traffic (outbound is without restriction) in security group, which is attached to the EC2-Classic instance, for port 3306 and public IP addresses of Replication instance & AuroraDB in VPC.  
* via Classic Link, AuroraDB in VPC & EC2-classic instance has attached same SG group, which allows incoming port 3306 for external IP of all three instances, CIDR of my VPC and it still doesnt work. :(

I stopped FW, iptables, etc on server

Comment: Do you have any firewall on the EC2-Classic instance? Does the user you use for the database endpoint has the read/write rights on the database?

Comment: how I wrote before, I disabled FW on instance, and I am able to remote connect to the MariaDB on that instance from different instances.
the settings which I set for the second ec2 instance with which I tried to connect to this EC2-classic with MariaDB, I set the same settings for replication instance

Answer (score 8):

You must add the security group from your DMS replication instance to your RDS database associated security group as an authorised inbound traffic.

- Go to Database Migration Service dashboard and them to "Replication Instances"
- Select your replication instance to get the "VPC Security Group"